# GMSMapView of Google Maps SDK in iOS Shows Nothing

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm developing an iOS app using Google Maps SDK 1.9.13516.0. A wired bug I am facing is that when my app is switched to background for several minutes, the GMSMapView shows nothing when my app is switched to foreground.
The GMSMapView seems work because my app can still get data from GMSMapView object. I need to navigate to other view controllers and get back to make the GMSMapView alive.
Has anyone being facing this issue and be willing to give me some hints. Thank you so much.

[image: GMSMapView]

Comment: Show snippets of your code please..!

Comment: I'm wondering if the code below caused this problem.

-(void)dealloc{
 [self.gMapView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation"];
}

Comment: Are you displaying the map when you are not doing background/foreground? I mean, except this issue, your map is being displayed right ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replyiing. It finally worked last year. The issuse should be what you mentioned.

Comment: If it worked please add an answer or show the code that failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try initing mapView like this.

> ```
> override func loadView() {
>     super.loadView()
>
>     let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.868,
>                                           longitude: 151.2086,
>                                           zoom: 14)
>     let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
>     view = mapView
> }
> ```

Or just set mapview frames and addSubview(mapview).